# Extracting point data with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, coordinates, qgis-3, extract

How to extract `x,y,z` values from a point/node in PyQGIS?

I am working on QGIS 3.

Answer (score 2):

The x, y and z values are accessible via methods of a QgsPoint object as documented on https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Point/QgsPoint.html

```
pt = QgsPoint(43.4, 5.3)
print(pt.x())
print(pt.y())
print(pt.z())
```

Comment: But if you have a geometry object. How do you get it out?

Comment: You asked about a point object. If that was not what you meant, please clarify in your question. Provide a minimal example to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I have a code that prints out layer geometries in the form of “<QgsGeometry: PointZ (149378.00 6568596.35 0)>”. How can I dig deeper and extract the values in that datatype?

Comment: Can you try https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Geometry/QgsGeometry.html -> .asPoint()?

Comment: That just strips it of the hight value. “<QgsGeometry: POINT(149255.987 6568569.3599)>”